# What is the best way to communicate with Bonjour?

Tags: java, networking, bonjour

There is a nice method provided by Bonjour: `DNSSD.browse("_killerapp._tcp", this);`. As the first argument of this method I give type of service which potentially can be available in the network, and as the second argument I give a "callback object". The considered method "browse" for the services of the indicated type (first argument).

During the browsing it can "find" and then "lose" a service. If service is found (lost) bonjour call serviceFound (serviceLost) method of the callback object. The serviceFound is called with some parameters of the found service. In more details:

```
serviceFound(DNSSDService browser, int flags, int ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain)
```

But to get the IP address and port of the service we need to do additional operation (people call it "to resolve a service"). This is logic is kind of strange to me. Why this information cannot be given by serviceFound? I mean why Bonjour cannot resolve the service automatically whenever it finds a service.

Anyway, I just accept the given logic and try to use it. From the `serviceFound` I call `DNSSD.resolve(0, ifIndex, serviceName, regType, domain, this)`.

As before I give a callback object to the `resolve` (the last argument). Unfortunately I need to use different classes to provide the callback objects for `browse` and `resolve`. The reason for that is that `browse` and `resolve` can call a `operationFailed` method of the callback object and, if I use callback objects from the same class I will not know which method is calling the `operationFailed` (`browse` or `resolve`).

So, I create a separate class to instantiate a callback object for the `resolve` method. In this class I have a method called `serviceResolved` which is called by Bonjour with IP address and port of the resolved service:

```
serviceResolved(DNSSDService resolver, int flags, int ifIndex, String fullname, String hostname, int port, TXTRecord txtRecord)
```

I think that the IP address and port should be fields of the objects which perform browsing. So, in the `serviceResolved` I have IP and port and I want to set these values to the corresponding field of the instance which `browse` the service. But how can I do it? This instance is not given as an argument of the `serviceResolved` method. So, it is invisible!

Moreover, I see that serviceResolved and serviceFound take, as a first argument, `DNSSDService resolver`. Does anybody know what is it? May be this object can be used to set parameters of the service? I know that an object of this type is returned by the `browse`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but would like to point out that,
besides the Bonjour library, you may want to try JmDNS, which is a pure Java, open sourced module.